# Can I set up a remote connection to Mongo on cloud nine?

Tags: mongodb, cloud9-ide

I would like to use a GUI instead of just the Mongo shell on my cloud nine instance. Is there a way I can connect a tool like Mongo chef to the Mongo server that's running on cloud nine?

Comment: if you can connect via mongo shell, you should be able to connect via most tools.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: I have to SSH in before starting the shell though; I can't launch a show from my local instance (as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Cloud9 workspaces only forward one port, port 8080. So in order for your GUI app to gain access to your mongodb, it will have to be listening on `0.0.0.0:8080` and you have set your application url to public (if you don't know how to do that, just click on 'Share' near the top left of the IDE, and click 'Public' next to 'Application').

However, the problem is that since you're also probably running your application on port 8080, you'll have to do some housekeeping and use different ports for Mongodb while your app is running and when you need to access the db using your GUI app.